# How to limit this swipe refresh if its only at top?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

This is my code which I used to make my data fetched from my data base in form of a list.But it is refreshing at all time when scroll down after a scrolled up for an instant . I need to make the refresh avail only when it is at top.

```
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
 import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.AdapterView;
 import android.widget.ListView;
 import android.widget.ProgressBar;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 import com.shuan.Project.R;
 import com.shuan.Project.Utils.Common;
 import com.shuan.Project.adapter.ConnectAdapter;
 import com.shuan.Project.asyncTasks.GetHome;
 import com.shuan.Project.asyncTasks.GetPost;
 import com.shuan.Project.employer.PostViewActivity;
 import com.shuan.Project.list.Sample;

 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.HashMap;

public class OffersFragment extends Fragment {


   private ArrayList<Sample> list;
   private ConnectAdapter adapter;
private ListView listView;
private HashMap<String, String> cData;
private Common mApp;
private Context mContext;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private SwipeRefreshLayout swipe;


public OffersFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    mContext=getActivity();
    mApp= (Common) mContext.getApplicationContext();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_employer_home, container, false);

    swipe = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipe);
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.post);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

    list = new ArrayList<Sample>();

    new GetPost(getActivity(), listView, progressBar, mApp.getPreference().getString(Common.u_id,""),"all", swipe).execute();


    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            TextView txt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.jId);
            TextView txt1= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.frm_id);
            Intent in=new Intent(getActivity(),PostViewActivity.class);
            in.putExtra("jId",txt.getText().toString());
            in.putExtra("frmId",txt1.getText().toString());
            in.putExtra("apply","no");
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });
    swipe.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            new GetHome(getActivity(), listView, progressBar, mApp.getPreference().getString(Common.u_id, ""), "all",swipe).execute();
        }
    });

    return view;
   }

 }
```

my xml file

```
   <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/swipe"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.shuan.Project.fragment.ConnectionFragment">


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/post"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: add you xml file to question'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my own solution  for the question above. We can solve the issue by change the above code like below.

```
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
 import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.AbsListView;
 import android.widget.AdapterView;
 import android.widget.ListView;
 import android.widget.ProgressBar;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 import com.shuan.Project.R;
 import com.shuan.Project.Utils.Common;
 import com.shuan.Project.adapter.ConnectAdapter;
 import com.shuan.Project.asyncTasks.GetHome;
 import com.shuan.Project.asyncTasks.GetPost;
 import com.shuan.Project.employer.PostViewActivity;
 import com.shuan.Project.list.Sample;

 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.HashMap;

 public class OffersFragment extends Fragment implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener {


private ArrayList<Sample> list;
private ConnectAdapter adapter;
private ListView listView;
private HashMap<String, String> cData;
private Common mApp;
private Context mContext;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private SwipeRefreshLayout swipe;
private int preLast;


public OffersFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    mContext=getActivity();
    mApp= (Common) mContext.getApplicationContext();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_employer_home, container, false);

    swipe = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipe);
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.post);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

    list = new ArrayList<Sample>();

    new GetPost(getActivity(), listView, progressBar, mApp.getPreference().getString(Common.u_id,""),"all", swipe).execute();


    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            TextView txt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.jId);
            TextView txt1= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.frm_id);
            Intent in=new Intent(getActivity(),PostViewActivity.class);
            in.putExtra("jId",txt.getText().toString());
            in.putExtra("frmId",txt1.getText().toString());
            in.putExtra("apply","no");
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });
    listView.setOnScrollListener(this);
    swipe.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            new GetHome(getActivity(), listView, progressBar, mApp.getPreference().getString(Common.u_id, ""), "all",swipe).execute();
        }
    });

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

}

@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

    if (view.getId() == R.id.post) {
        if (firstVisibleItem == 0) {
            swipe.setEnabled(true);
            int lastItem = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
            if (lastItem == totalItemCount) {
                if (preLast != lastItem) {
                    preLast = lastItem;
                    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "In Last", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }else{

            }
        } else {
            swipe.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Change your xml layout so SwipeRefreshLayout only wrap a scrollable view (your case the ListView).

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.shuan.Project.fragment.ConnectionFragment">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/post"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I am using the same xml file in my home too ,but no issues there. There i have written onscroll function

Comment: So there is actually an issue but you tackle it by writing codes inside onScroll method and listen whether the list reaches the top, then run the refresh method. Sometimes we need that hack (For example if there are more than one scrollable views) , but in your case, you just have to put the SwipeRefreshLayout to wrap ListView only and they will do the job for you.

Comment: Works for me. I had two LinearLayouts and ExpandlableListView in SwipeRefreshLayout and it refreshed everytime I swiped up. Once the SwipeRefreshLayout wraps only the ListView, the refresh event is triggered only on top. Mark this as correct answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.enhancedListView.EnhancedListView
        android:id="@+id/listaNoticias"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >
    </com.enhancedListView.EnhancedListView>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.principal, container, false);

    swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
    swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
    swipeLayout.setColorSchemeColors(android.R.color.holo_green_dark, 
            android.R.color.holo_red_dark, 
            android.R.color.holo_blue_dark, 
            android.R.color.holo_orange_dark); (...)

@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    new myTask().execute();     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit old, but in 2019 this is the correct answer: you have to include RecyclerView inside of NestedScrollView in order for SwipeRefreshLayout to behave properly, like this:

```
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this lines of code
note : LinearLayoutManager should be define separately

```
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());    
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);       
mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);


      mSwipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled
(mLinearLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == 0);
}
});
```

findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == 0 means at the top of recyclerview